# Testing complex React components with Mocha/Chai

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, fixed-data-table

I'm working on [addons](https://github.com/gforge/fixed-data-table-addons) for [fixed-data-table](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table) and [its sibling](https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2/) but I'm struggling with setting up the tests using a Mocha/Chai setup. The error I get is:

```
 TypeError: obj.indexOf is not a function
      at Assertion.include (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:228:45)
      at Assertion.assert (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addChainableMethod.js:84:49)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/HOC/addFilter_test.jsx:48:23)
```

All the tutorials that I've managed to locate show how to handle testing trivial components, I believe the error results from that the node is a complex component.

My question: **How do I more complex components?** In particular I would like some help with:

1. Finding the node that contains the value of that cell
2. Remain ignorant when testing of how a cell is implemented, e.g. if it's a `div` or a `td`
3. See if an element/cell in row 1 appears before or after an element that is supposed to be in row 2 (for validating sorting)

### Background

#### Core test-setup:

```
import React from 'react';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import { Table, Column, Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import chaiJquery from 'chai-jquery';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import Data from '../stub/Data';

// Set up testing environment to run like a browser in the command line
global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
const $ = jquery(global.window);

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

Wrapper.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node,
};

// build 'renderComponent' helper that should render a given react class
function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props) {
  let node = null;
  if (typeof (ComponentClass) === 'function') {
    TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Wrapper ref={n => (node = n)}>
        <ComponentClass {...props} />
      </Wrapper>);
  } else {
    TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ComponentClass {...props} ref={n => (node = n)} />);
  }

  return node;
}

// Set up chai-jquery
chaiJquery(chai, chai.util, $);

const TextCell = ({ rowIndex, columnKey, data }) => (
  <Cell>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[columnKey]}
  </Cell>);

TextCell.propTypes = {
  rowIndex: React.PropTypes.number,
  columnKey: React.PropTypes.string,
    data: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

#### The data stub:

```
class Data {
  constructor(nrows = 4) {
    this.size = nrows;
  }

  getSize() {
    return (this.size);
  }

  getObjectAt(index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
      return (null);
    }

    return {
      id: index,
      name: `Test name no ${index}`,
    };
  }
}

export default Data;
```

#### The actual test:

```
describe('Basic test', () => {
  it('some test', () => {
    const data = new Data();

    const node = renderComponent(props =>
      (<Table
        rowHeight={50}
        headerHeight={50}
        height={500}
        width={500}
        filters={{ name: '' }}
        rowsCount={data.getSize()}
        {...props}
      >
        <Column
          columnKey="id"
          width={250}
          header={<Cell>ID</Cell>}
          cell={<TextCell data={data} />}
        />
        <Column
          columnKey="name"
          width={250}
          header={<Cell>Name</Cell>}
          cell={<TextCell data={data} />}
        />
      </Table>));

    for (let i = 0; i < data.getSize(); i += 1) {
      expect(node).to.contains(`Test name no ${i}`);
    }
  });
});
```

## Update

Changed to [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) as suggested:

```
import React from 'react';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import { Table, Column, Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';
import Data from '../stub/Data';

Error.stackTraceLimit = 10;
chai.use(chaiEnzyme);

const TextCell = ({ rowIndex, columnKey, data }) => (
  <Cell id={`${rowIndex}_${columnKey}`}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[columnKey]}
  </Cell>);

TextCell.propTypes = {
  rowIndex: React.PropTypes.number,
  columnKey: React.PropTypes.string,
    data: React.PropTypes.object,
};

describe('Basic test', () => {
  it('some test', () => {
    const data = new Data();

    const node = shallow(<Table
      rowHeight={50}
      headerHeight={50}
      height={500}
      width={500}
      filters={{ name: '' }}
      rowsCount={data.getSize()}
    >
      <Column
        columnKey="id"
        width={250}
        header={<Cell>ID</Cell>}
        cell={<TextCell data={data} />}
      />
      <Column
        columnKey="name"
        width={250}
        header={<Cell>Name</Cell>}
        cell={<TextCell data={data} />}
      />
    </Table>);

    for (let i = 0; i < data.getSize(); i += 1) {
      expect(node.find(`#${i}_name`)).to.have.length(1, `Can't find cell with id: ${i}_name`);
    }
  });
});
```

I've added an auto-generated id-marker to the `Textcell` and tried to find it using `` .find(`#${i}_name`) `` but it doesn't find the object. I've checked the output of the wrapped element using `node.html()` and it does contain the cell with the proper ID:

```
<div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1" id="0_name">
  <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
      <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">
        Test name no 0
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it is an option, I think it is easier to do tests with Jest and Enzyme (I use chai and chai-enzyme)... Look at my project to see an example... https://github.com/lucaskatayama/react-weathericons

Comment: @LucasKatayama sounds like a good way for reducing the amount of boilerplate - not sure if it addresses the core question: how to check the presence of data down the node-tree?

Comment: With enzyme you could find the node you want and then apply assertions. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.md

Comment: @LucasKatayama looks very interesting. Will test tomorrow. Any ideas on checking the order of the nodes?

Comment: Never did that before.. I think a way is to check position by key prop... Anotger cool think.. enzyme works on virtual dom tree.. ao you could check either the real dom by calling render.. or not.. you can mount a complex container using mount.. or a simple component using shallow .. which is great for unit tests

Comment: Don't know whats happen to your comment... Stackoverflow asked to move to chat ... but it removed comment and do nothing else

Comment: @LucasKatayama - added an example with enzyme. Think I just solved it by using `mount` instead of `shallow`. I think the sort-issue could be solved using the html-string together with [regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) expressions. Do you want me to write the answer or do you want to do it? (Not sure why the chat didn't work)

Comment: You can write... I don't get it how you solved the sort...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128951/discussion-between-max-gordon-and-lucas-katayama).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *Lucas Katayama* for you suggestions of using [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme). Note that the `mount` has to bused or the `find` won't identify the sub-elements.

The sort-problem was solved by finding the first id, replacing everything before and then searching the remainder for the next ID.

```
import React from 'react';
import { describe, it, beforeEach } from 'mocha';
import { Table, Column, Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import Data from '../stub/Data';

Error.stackTraceLimit = 10;
chai.use(chaiEnzyme);

const TextCell = ({ rowIndex, columnKey, data }) => (
  <Cell id={`${rowIndex}_${columnKey}`}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[columnKey]}
  </Cell>);

TextCell.propTypes = {
  rowIndex: React.PropTypes.number,
  columnKey: React.PropTypes.string,
  data: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Data),
};

describe('Basic test', () => {
  const data = new Data();
  let node;
  beforeEach(() => (
    node = mount(<Table
      rowHeight={50}
      headerHeight={50}
      height={500}
      width={500}
      filters={{ name: '' }}
      rowsCount={data.getSize()}
    >
      <Column
        columnKey="id"
        width={250}
        header={<Cell>ID</Cell>}
        cell={<TextCell data={data} />}
      />
      <Column
        columnKey="name"
        width={250}
        header={<Cell>Name</Cell>}
        cell={<TextCell data={data} />}
      />
    </Table>)
  ));

  it('test that cells exist', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.getSize(); i += 1) {
      expect(node.find(`#${i}_id`)).to.have.length(1, `Can't find cell with id: ${i}_id`);
      expect(node.find(`#${i}_name`)).to.have.length(1, `Can't find cell with id: ${i}_name`);
    }
  });

  it('sort test', () => {
    const txt = node.html();
    for (let i = 0; i < data.getSize() - 1; i += 1) {
      const first = new RegExp(`.+id="${i}_id"(.+)`);
      const second = new RegExp(`id="${i + 1}_id"`);
      expect(txt.replace(first, '($1)').match(second)).to.not.be.null;
    }
  });
});
```